I want to return a key using Lodash when it contains a particular value
I have an object like this:
const obj = {
  'MONEY-OUT': {
    USD: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    EUR: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  },
  'MONEY-IN': {
    USD: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    EUR: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
  },
};

and I want to create a function that returns either the key MONEY-OUT / MONEY-IN  if that key contains a character in its array using Lodash.
I have 2 variables in this function: currency, search_string
For example, my variable values for this function are 'EUR' and 'k'  so I need my function to return the key MONEY-IN

What have you tried? What happens if the currency and search string appear in both keys?

There's zero reason to use Lodash or any other utility library for this.
You can use Array.prototype.find() to find the first object entry (key / value) pair matching your criteria, then return the key for that entry


const obj = {
  'MONEY-OUT': {
    USD: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    EUR: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  },
  'MONEY-IN': {
    USD: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    EUR: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
  },
};

const findKey = (currency, search_string) =>
  Object.entries(obj).find(([, v]) =>
    v[currency]?.includes(search_string),
  )?.[0];

console.log('EUR[k]', findKey('EUR', 'k'));
console.log('USD[b]', findKey('USD', 'b'));
console.log('GBP[z]', findKey('GPB', 'z'));




I actually was looking into Lodash since most of our functions to get data from arrays and objects already use the library. However your solution I think is simpler in terms of implementation, agree on not using Lodash for this. Thanks, Phil!

Since the answer you are searching for a lodash based solution and above

There's zero reason to use Lodash or any other utility library for
this.
You can use Array.prototype.find() to find the first object entry (key
/ value) pair matching your criteria, then return the key for that
entry

@Phil provided answer is based upon Array.prototype.find(), Here's how you can achieve what you are looking for using the library lodash:
Refer the below code for reference:


const obj = {
      'MONEY-OUT': {
        USD: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        EUR: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
      },
      'MONEY-IN': {
        USD: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
        EUR: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
      },
    };

    function findKeyByValue(obj, currency, search_string) {
      return _.findKey(obj, (value) => {
        return _.get(value, currency, []).includes(search_string);
      });
    }

    function findKeyAndCurrency(obj, currency, search_string) {
      const topKey = findKeyByValue(obj, currency, search_string);
      return topKey ? { topKey, currency } : null;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(findKeyAndCurrency(obj, 'EUR', 'k')));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(findKeyAndCurrency(obj, 'USD', 'g')));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(findKeyAndCurrency(obj, 'USD', 'a')));
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js">   
</script>




Thanks for this @SELA! Appreciate you pouring in your thoughts here.

Happy to help :)  @testerJuan
